# TravisCI Android build fails

Tags: android, travis-ci

I try to run my configuration but it fails.

Here is my configuration:

```
language: android
jdk: oraclejdk8
env:
  matrix:
   - ANDROID_TARGET=android-22  ANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a
android:
  components:
    - build-tools-21.1.2
    - android-22
    - sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-22
    - extra

# Emulator Management: Create, Start and Wait
before_script:
  - echo no | android create avd --force -n test -t $ANDROID_TARGET --abi $ANDROID_ABI
  - emulator -avd test -no-skin -no-audio -no-window &
  - android-wait-for-emulator
  - adb shell input keyevent 82 &

script: cd MVVM-Example && ./gradlew app:connectAndroidTest -PdisablePreDex
```

https://github.com/AHarazim/android-mvvm-example/blob/devTravisCi/.travis.yml

Here you can see the output:

https://travis-ci.org/AHarazim/android-mvvm-example

Build failed with an exception.

I try also to run the build with

```
./gradlew app:connectAndroidTest --info
```

but there was no exception.

When I try to run with

```
./gradlew app:connectAndroidTest --debug
```

I get:

```
The log length has exceeded the limit of 4 Megabytes (this usually means that test suite is raising the same exception over and over).
The build has been terminated.
```

Is there any magic trick to see the log or to see what the problem is?

Comment: It is weird. It almost looks like you are using `gradlew` with `--info`. Are you adding extra debugging somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There s a lot of build script downloading logging going on.
Try adding the following to your .yml file:

```
env:
  global:
  - TERM=dumb
```

This should minify those logs, and help keep them within the limit.

Comment: Wow, thx. Awesome! Now I see the right errors! dankjewel, buur ;-)